# Hazelcast max size of distributed map not respected

Tags: java, out-of-memory, hazelcast

Hazelcast 3.3 does not respect the JVM size of a Map (MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE). MaxSize 20 MB and LRU eviction policy is used in our example.

```
mapCfg.setEvictionPolicy(MapConfig.EvictionPolicy.LRU);
mapCfg.setEvictionPercentage(20); 
MaxSizeConfig maxSizeCfg = new MaxSizeConfig(20, MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE); 
mapCfg.setMaxSizeConfig(maxSizeCfg);
```

This is a real problem for us as we have more data than heap and so we get a lot of OutOfMemoryError's.

Anybody else experiencing the same? Is our config wrong? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

new MaxSizeConfig(20, MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE);  think you need to make that higher